# How to make the file accessible only through its own server?

Tags: apache2, dns, .htaccess

I've added this in the  `.htaccess` the file located in the root of the project:

```
<Files *.php>
    Require host lamtakam.test lamtakam.com
    Require ip ::1 95.216.xx.xx
</Files>
```

I've used `xx.xx` to keep my real ip hidden in a public community, in reality, there are numbers instead of `x`s.

Now I need to call a file daily (using a cron job `crontab`) from the same server, something like this:

```
0 22 * * * wget /path/to/file.php
```

But I get this error:

```
--2020-09-13 13:33:55--  https://lamtakam.com/path/to/file.php
Resolving lamtakam.com (lamtakam.com)... 104.31.74.192, 172.67.174.239, 104.31.75.192, ...
Connecting to lamtakam.com (lamtakam.com)|104.31.74.192|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2020-09-13 13:33:55 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Note: **I use Cloudflare** and these IPs belongs to it: `104.31.74.192, 172.67.174.239, 104.31.75.192`

Any idea how can I make `file.php` accessible when I can it from the same server? (And not from anywhere else)

Comment: @user68186 ubuntu 18.04 .. And what you mean by "distribution "?

Comment: Did you try `localhost/path/to/file.php` (assuming you are not using "virtual hosts" on your web server)?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It throws `Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:443... connected. ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches requested host name ‘localhost’. To connect to localhost insecurely, use --no-check-certificate'.`

Comment: `wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost/...` ?

Comment: Consider using scp instead of wget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trick the server via adding the following record in your `/etc/hosts` file, that server as local DNS, thus the Cloudflare's DNS setup will be ignored:

```
95.216.xx.xx lamtakam.com
```

You can't use `https://` for `localhost/` because the SSL/HTTPS certificates are issued for a concrete domain name, i.e. *lamtakam.com*, etc.

You could bind `lamtakam.com` and probably `lamtakam.test` to the loop back interface (`127.0.0.1` for IPv4 and `::1` for IPv6) by modifying the relevant line of `/etc/hosts` in this way:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost lamtakam.com www.lamtakam.com lamtakam.test www.lamtakam.test
```

In this case you should edit the `.htaccess` file in a way as this:

```
<Files *.php>
    Require host lamtakam.test lamtakam.com
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

- Note `::1` is the IPv6 loopback interface, but we didn't created an appropriate entry   in the `/etc/hosts` file, so we do not need impossible require rule for that IP.

This second approach (by using the loopback interface) is more flexible, because even you change the server's public IP you wont need to change your `.htaccess` setup.